# Redirect instead of HTTP403

Tags: python, proxy, webfiltering

I'm trying to make a proxy with a Blocklist. I initially used 403 when a user goes to a blocked page. However, it doesn't work with HTTPS and returns ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED as explained in [Respond with 403 in an HTTPS proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60145682/respond-with-403-in-an-https-proxy) 
Thus, I want to redirect the user to a html page like [this](https://azlancoding.github.io/Blocked) 
This is my code:

```
import socket
import threading
import signal
import sys
import fnmatch
import errno
import time
import pdb
import re
from time import gmtime, strftime, localtime
import logging
import config
import rule
import tag as tag_store
from Ignite import flame
core = flame()

p=re.compile('(http:\/\/)?([\w\.-]*)(\:(\d*))?(\/.*)?')
thread_logger = logging.getLogger('thread')
access_logger = logging.getLogger('access')
csv_logger = logging.getLogger('csv')

def proxy(browser_conn, client_addr):
    print("hi")
    def ishostAllowed(host):
        print("\n\nHost:")
        print(str(host))
        access_logger.info(str(host))
        if host.split('.')[-1].isdigit():
            thread_logger.warn("Invalid host:".format(host),extra=req)            
            return core.check_allow(host)
        #pdb.set_trace()
        tags=tag_store.get(host)
        if not tags:
            thread_logger.warn("{0} isn't allowed: empty tags".format(host),extra=req)            
            return core.check_allow(host)
        for tag in tag_store.get(host):
            if not rule.isTagAllowed(tag):
                thread_logger.warn("{0}:{1} isn't allowed".format(host,tag),extra=req)
                return core.check_allow(host)
        return core.check(host)

    def proxy_http(request):
        try:
            # create a socket to connect to the web server
            #pdb.set_trace()
            server_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            server_conn.settimeout(config.connection_timeout)
            server_conn.connect((request['host'], request['port']))
            server_conn.sendall(request['raw_data'])                           # send request to webserver

            while 1:
                data = server_conn.recv(config.max_request_len)          # receive data from web server
                if (len(data) > 0):
                    browser_conn.send(data)                               # send to browser
                else:
                    break
        except socket.error as error_msg:
            thread_logger.error(str(error_msg)+":"+str(request),extra=req);
        finally:
            if server_conn:
                server_conn.close()
            if browser_conn:
                browser_conn.close()
            
        return
    
    def response(status,message):
        reply = "HTTP/1.1 {0} {1}\r\n"
        reply += "Proxy-agent: Sinktrap\r\n"
        reply += "\r\n"
        reply = reply.format(status,message);
        #pdb.set_trace()
        browser_conn.sendall( reply.encode() )

    def proxy_https(request):
        #pdb.set_trace()
        try:
            server_conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            # If successful, send 200 code response
            server_conn.connect((req['host'], req['port']))
            response(200,'Connection established')
        except socket.error as err:
        # If the connection could not be established, exit
        # Should properly handle the exit with http error code here
            thread_logger.error("Cannot establish https connection:"+err,extra=req);
            if server_conn:
                server_conn.close()
            if browser_conn:
                browser_conn.close()
            return

        # Indiscriminately forward bytes
        browser_conn.setblocking(0)
        server_conn.setblocking(0)

        timeout=time.time()+60 # 1 minute
        while timeout-time.time()>0:
            request_done=False
            replied_done=False
            try:
                    request =browser_conn.recv(config.max_request_len)           # receive data from browser
                    if (len(request) > 0):
                        server_conn.sendall(request)                               # send to web server
                    else:
                        request_done=True
                    #hread_logger.info("REQUEST len: " + str(len(request)),extra=req);
            except socket.error as e:
                    if e.errno==errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                            time.sleep(0.1)
                            pass
                    else:
                            thread_logger.error("pipe error:"+str(e),extra=req);
                            break                        
            try:
                    reply = server_conn.recv(config.max_request_len)          # receive data from web server
                    if (len(reply) > 0):
                        browser_conn.sendall(reply)                               # send to browser
                    else:
                        replied_done=True
                    #thread_logger.info("reply len: " + str(len(reply)),extra=req);
            except socket.error as e:

                    if e.errno==errno.EWOULDBLOCK:
                            time.sleep(0.1)
                            pass
                    else:
                            thread_logger.error("pipe error:"+str(e),extra=req);
                            break  
            if request_done and replied_done:
                break

        server_conn.close()
        browser_conn.close()
       

    raw_data = browser_conn.recv(config.max_request_len)        # get the request from browser
    req={'raw_data':raw_data,
         'tname' : threading.currentThread().getName(),
         'client_ip' : client_addr[0],
         'client_port' : client_addr[1]
        }
    thread_logger.info("REQUEST: {0}".format(raw_data),extra=req);
    #pdb.set_trace()

    try:
        # request_line is the first one. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html
        msg_body_pos=len(raw_data)
        for i in range(4,len(raw_data)):
            if raw_data[i-4:i].decode()=='\r\n\r\n':
                msg_body_pos=i
                break
        lines=raw_data[:msg_body_pos-4].decode('utf-8').split('\r\n')
        if len(lines[0])<16:
            thread_logger.warn("INVALU REQUEST:{0}".format(raw_data),extra=req);
            return
        headers = {k:v for k,v in (x.split(':',1) for x in lines[1:]) }
        if 'Referer' in headers:
            req['Referer']=headers['Referer']
        else:
            req['Referer']=''
        if 'User-Agent' in headers:
            req['User-Agent']=headers['User-Agent']
        else:
            req['User-Agent']=''
        req['request_line'] =lines[0]        
        req['method'],req['request_uri'],req['http_version']=lines[0].split(' ')

        #check if the first line is valid request. request_line might be empty
        if not req['method'] or not req['request_uri'] or not req['http_version']:
            thread_logger.warn("INVALU REQUEST:{0}".format(raw_data),extra=req);
            return
    except Exception as e:
        thread_logger.error("INVALU REQUEST:{0} {1}".format(e, raw_data),extra=req);
        logging.exception("INVALU REQUEST")
        return
    access_logger.info("",extra=req)
    #pdb.set_trace()
    m=p.match(req['request_uri'])
    req['host']=m.group(2)
    req['port']=int(m.group(4)) if m.group(4) else 80


    # Check if request is allowed or not
    if not ishostAllowed(req['host']):
        csv_logger.info("blocked",extra=req);
        thread_logger.warn("Block REQUEST:{0}".format(raw_data),extra=req);
        response(403,"The website has been blocked by Ignite's proxy.")
        #Breq = req
        #Breq['host'] = "azlancoding.github.io/Blocked"
        #proxy_https(Breq)
        #response(307,"https://azlancoding.github.io/BLOCKED")
        return

    csv_logger.info("allowed",extra=req);
    #pdb.set_trace() 
    if req['method']=='CONNECT':
        proxy_https(req)
    else:
        proxy_http(req)
```

The original proxy is [pcxy](https://github.com/limin/pcxy) 
See my github project [here](https://github.com/AzlanCoding/Student-Ignite)

Comment: If you could send back your own response to a proxies TLS connection the whole idea of the encryption would not work, would it? Though you could break it on purpose with a mitm attack by installing a CA certificate in the client.

Comment: This proxy runs within the users computer (localhost)

Comment: That does not make a difference.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to these web proxies and stuff. Would you mind explaining to me how it would works and what I can do to achieve that?